# Insert space between characters regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm very new to regex, and i'm trying to find instances in a string where there exists a word consisting of either the letter `w` or `e` followed by 2 digits, such as `e77` `w10` etc.

Here's the regex that I currently have, which I think finds that (correct me if i'm wrong)

`([e|w])\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?`

How can I add a space right after the letter `e` or `w`? If there are no instances where the criteria is met, I would like to keep the string as is. Do I need to use re.sub? I've read a bit about that.

Input: `hello e77 world`

Desired output: `hello e 77 world`

Thank You.

Comment: Did you not *test* your regex? Because it doesn't actually find `e77` in your input.

Comment: try testing your regex here https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: @WayneWerner I think it's finding it, isn't it? http://regexr.com/3e1j5 However, I know its not entirelly accurate because it's matching all occurrences of e/w as well.

Comment: Perhaps this would help: https://regex101.com/r/aC4aE2/1 ?

Comment: @hl95 it's match it, yes, but it's matching too many cases since pretty much everything after `\d{0,2}` is just never being matched.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your regex needs to just look like this:

```
([ew])(\d{2})
```

if you want to only match specifically 2 digits, or

```
([ew])(\d{1,2})
```

if you also want to match single digits like `e4`

The brackets are called capturing groups and could be back referenced in a search and replace, or with python, using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

your replace string should look like

```
\1 \2
```

So it should be as simple as a line like:

```
re.sub(r'([ew])(\d{1,2})', r'\1 \2', your_string)
```

EDIT: working code

```
>>> import re
>>> your_string = 'hello e77 world'
>>>
>>> re.sub(r'([ew])(\d{1,2})', r'\1 \2', your_string)
'hello e 77 world'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're after:

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'([ew])(\d{1,2})', r'\g<1> \g<2>', 'hello e77 world'))
```