# insert space between regex match

Tags: python, regex

I want to un-join typos in my string by locating them using regex and insert a space character between the matched expression.

I tried the solution to a similar question ... but it did not work for me -([Insert space between characters regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998547/insert-space-between-characters-regex)); solution-  to use the replace string as '\1 \2' in re.sub .

```
import re

corpus = ''' 
This is my corpus1a.I am looking to convert it into a 2corpus 2b.
'''

clean = re.compile('\.[^(\d,\s)]')
corpus = re.sub(clean,' ', corpus)

clean2 = re.compile('\d+[^(\d,\s,\.)]')
corpus = re.sub(clean2,'\1 \2', corpus)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
This is my corpus 1 a. I am looking to convert it into a 2 corpus 2 b.
```

Comment: Can you describe more what you're trying to do? Find all "a." "b." and insert a space before and after?

Comment: Capture group goes outside character class, two capture groups necessary if you have two references.

Comment: I am trying to find all patterns (digit followed by alphabet, and alphabet followed by digit) and add a space character between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the capture group parentheses *around* the patterns that match each string that you want to copy to the result.

There's also no need to use `+` after `\d`. You only need to match the last digit of the number.

```
clean = re.compile(r'(\d)([^\d,\s])')
corpus = re.sub(clean, r'\1 \2', corpus)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/R1Dup9/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I tried rectifying the capture group parentheses, but the output eliminates the matches rather than inserting spaces between the capture groups as shown by your demo. Here is my output for the same code-

"This is my corpus .I am looking to convert it into a  orpus  ."

Comment: Make sure you're using raw strings. Otherwise `\1` and `\2` mean the characters with codes 1 and 2, not back-references to the capture gruops.

Comment: **Always** use raw strings when working with regexp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about other possible inputs, we might be able to add spaces using an expression similar to:

```
(\d+)([a-z]+)\b
```

after that we would replace any two spaces with a single space and it might work, not sure though:

```
import re

print(re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", re.sub(r"(\d+)([a-z]+)\b", " \\1 \\2", "This is my corpus1a.I am looking to convert it into a 2corpus 2b")))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/4rPno9/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/4rPno9/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Capture groups, marked by parenthesis `(` and `)`, should be around the patterns you want to match.

So this should work for you

```
clean = re.compile(r'(\d+)([^\d,\s])')
corpus = re.sub(clean,'\1 \2', corpus)
```

The regex `(\d+)([^\d,\s])` reads: match 1 or more digits (`\d+`) as group 1 (first set of parenthesis), match non-digit and non-whitespace as group 2.

The reason why your's doesn't work was that you did not have parenthesis surrounding the patterns you want to reuse.

Comment: I think, as Barmar mentioned in his comment above, the replace string needs to be raw string. Else it wont treat it as a capture group.